# Get class with string then get following string

Tags: javascript

I need to get the first class that has the string `"Routed:"` 
then get the next string that follows that/ attempted to use `document.querySelector` not sure if this is the correct direction

```
<td class="msvb2">Routed:</td>
<td class="msvb2">AAZ12332</td>
```

Edit update:

`var tds = document.getElementsByClassName('ms-cellstyle ms-vb2');`
`var value, index = 0, length = tds.length;`
`for ( ; index < length; index++) {`

`-   if (tds[index].textContent == 'Routed:') {`
`-         value = tds[index].nextElementSibling.textContent;`
`-        break;`
`-    }`
`}`
`document.getElementsByClassName('ms-cellstyle ms-vb2').textContent = value;`
`console.log(textContent);`

is returning : 
`Uncaught ReferenceError: textContent is not defined`

Comment: Unclear what you are asking. You want to select an HTML element with a class containing the text `Routed`? Include your HTML and what you have attempted so far (and what the result was).

Comment: So you need to find the first *element* with the text `Routed:` and then get the text of the next sibling element? Is that correct?

Comment: Yeah, comments are not designed for that. You are supposed to edit the question.

Answer (score 2):

One way to do it is to select all the elements by the class and check their content, then when you find a matching content get the next sibling and get it's content.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/grkn9tpa/1/

```
var tds = document.getElementsByClassName('msvb2');
var value, index = 0, length = tds.length;
for ( ; index < length; index++) {
    if (tds[index].textContent == 'Routed:') {
        value = tds[index].nextElementSibling.textContent;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: log returns: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'textContent' of null

Comment: That issue doesn't happen in my simple example. I would need to see more of what you are doing. Do we know that every td will have a next sibling? Seems like you hit a scenario where there is no next sibling perhaps?

Comment: document.getElementById('msvb2').textContent = value; is what returns the error. but when i attempt to console log each of the variables nothing returns the routed: string. i looked over the js and seems perfect not sure what value i'm missing. after i get the Routed string i need to store the next sibling value AAZ12332

Comment: This is because, at least in your example above, msvb2 is your class. Not an element id.

Comment: it should be saving the next sibling element's textContent

Comment: im trying to post what i have into this comment box but keep losing my formatting. Do i update here or on the main question box. sorry im vry new here

Comment: @HazeTekLLC No problem, I would just update your question at the bottom noting its an update and there have been some changes to your issue after using suggested answers.

Comment: updated question. Returns: Uncaught ReferenceError: textContent is not defined

Comment: getElementsByClassName returns an array. document.getElementsByClassName('ms-cellstyle ms-vb2')[0].textContent

Comment: document.getElementsByClassName('ms-cellstyle ms-vb2')[0].textContent = value;
console.log(textContent);  returns: textContent is not defined

Comment: @HazeTekLLC as far I see from your code textContent is not a defined variable. Value is holding the value.

Answer (score 0):

Grab all the elements (td), loop through them, if you find a textContent that equals your search string, simply return the value of the next node in the loop.

```
function getNextValue (searchStr) {

  var nextVal = '', tds = document.querySelectorAll('td'); 

  for (var i=0; i<tds.length; i++) {
    if (tds[i].textContent === searchStr) {
      return tds[i+1].textContent;
    }
  }
};


console.log(   getNextValue('Routed:') );
```

Comment: returns: undefined in log

Comment: @HazeTekLLC if the `<td>` are not inside a `<table>`, it is invalid markup and `document.querySelectorAll('td');` will not be able to find them.